# [FromForm], [FromQuery],[FromBody],[FromHeader],[FromQuery],[FromRoute]

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

I am slowly learning the .Net Core. I caught my head thinking when to use  `[FromForm], [FromQuery],[FromBody],[FromHeader],[FromRoute] [FromService]`.
Could anyone please help me in understanding them because I am confused when to use which directive.

Comment: Read the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: You could refer to the official document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#binding-source-parameter-inference

Answer (score 15):

In simple words,

```
[FromQuery] is to get values from the query string
[FromRoute] is to get values from route data
[FromForm] is to get values from posted form fields
[FromBody] is to get values from the request body
[FromHeader] is to get values from HTTP headers
[FromService] will have value injected by the DI (Dependency Injection) resolver
```

**These attributes tell the MVC model binder from where to read the values from when the controller action is called or invoked.**

For more information on model binding and about the usage of the above attributes please refer the following MSDN link

[MSDN Reference -> Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Answer (score 6):

Here you can read a quite comprehensive article: https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1390/aspnet-core-web-api-attributes

But to be short: you can add these attributes to Web API controller methods (actions). More precisely to their parameters. For example:

```
public Task<Order> Get([FromQuery(Name = "identifier")] int id, [FromServices] IOrderService orderService)
```

They are telling the framework where to inject values from when the action is called. Most of them will use some part of the *http request* itself, but parameters decorated with `[FromService]` will have value injected by the DI resolver.